# Redirect to a specific section of another route on button click

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have my main page at `localhost` with a footer. Inside it, I have a contact button which is supposed to redirect the user to the contact section which is at the end of my other page at `localhost/home`. Each of my section have a `ref`. How could I manage that ?

The `home` page is formatted this way

```js
[...]
<div>
    <Component />
    <Component />
    <Component />
    <Component />
    <Contact ref={toto} /> // I want to be redirected directly here
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try calling this on `button` click:

```
toto.current.scrollIntoView();
```

Or, if you want it to scroll with an animation:

```
toto.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
```